# Restrict regression lines to data range for multiple lines on single plot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I performed an ANCOVA on the following data (location is a 5-way variable):

```
    id location sex pc1   pc1_haw  condition      ap
115 49   Hawaii   M  NA 0.8966151  -7.067692 103.014
116 27   Hawaii   M  NA 2.5289696  82.053163 197.674
117 33   Hawaii   M  NA 1.5887016  18.134019 130.765
118 34   Hawaii   M  NA        NA  21.040414 117.580
119 35   Hawaii   M  NA 2.5356646 -42.053211  93.099
120 55   Hawaii   M  NA 0.7416007 -61.093436 132.507

summary(aov(ap~condition*location))
                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
condition            1   6523    6523   8.553 0.00405 ** 
location             4  88048   22012  28.864 < 2e-16 ***
condition:location   4   8014    2003   2.627 0.03729 *  
Residuals          135 102954     763
```

And I would like to graphically represent the significant interaction. So a scatter plot that incorporates a regression line for each "location" that is limited in the x-axis to only the ranges of values for that "location."

I'm sure there is a faster way of making the graph itself, but this is what I've done so far:

```
##make different subsets of data for each location
h=subset(males, location=="Hawaii")
j=subset(males, location=="Jamaica")
i=subset(males, location=="India")
s=subset(males, location=="STX")
m=subset(males, location=="Mauritius") 

## make different regression lines for each location
reg_i=lm(i$ap~i$condition)
reg_j=lm(j$ap~j$condition)
reg_s=lm(s$ap~s$condition)
reg_h=lm(h$ap~h$condition)
reg_m=lm(m$ap~m$condition)

## made the initial plot and abline with just one set of data
plot(i$ap~i$condition, xlab="Condition", ylab="Anal Pad (mm^2)", xlim=c(-175,175), ylim=c(0,300), pch=1, frame.plot=F)

abline(reg_i)

## then added the rest to the existing plot with different colors and shapes
points(j$condition,j$ap, pch=16, col=2)
abline(reg_j, col=2)
points(h$condition,h$ap, pch=15, col=4)
abline(reg_h, col=4)
points(s$condition,s$ap, pch=17, col=5)
abline(reg_s, col=5)
points(m$condition,m$ap, pch=18, col=6)
abline(reg_m, col=6)
```

I have the plot, I just want to be able to limit the regression lines to their respective values' ranges.

Here is the subset of data for "i", dput(i):

structure(list(id = c(51L, 50L, 49L, 48L, 47L, 46L, 42L, 40L, 
39L, 38L, 36L, 34L, 32L, 29L, 27L, 26L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 18L, 17L, 
15L, 31L), location = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Hawaii", "India", "Jamaica", "Mauritius", "STX"
), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), pc1 = c(0.836604139, 
1.321670843, 0.16817092, 0.039442128, 0.5223987, 0.410205403, 
0.994359741, 0.973975983, 1.742148099, -0.94672848, 0.798914775, 
-0.253556712, 2.316481173, -0.247525226, 1.389016661, 2.178869889, 
-0.517312934, 0.875533845, -0.333274608, NA, -1.899439969, 0.800857011, 
1.26994084), pc1_haw = c(0.474631073, 1.484601953, 0.147219614, 
0.278126658, 0.318994781, 0.608755224, 1.037980473, 1.087243461, 
1.413423102, -0.534238012, 1.37545187, -0.045763413, 1.720985159, 
0.278497659, 1.085098831, 1.513901703, 0.074479968, 0.676913565, 
0.172891392, 0.71098318, -1.373299481, -0.094551205, 0.909750434
), condition = c(53.5063398, -39.34044114, -78.65535012, -120.2468368, 
-25.24683677, -12.51917901, -5.927692357, -57.63406675, -15.70215231, 
-76.94897573, -48.08938228, -44.90217355, 76.79996541, -106.7234357, 
0.093591019, -6.042580098, -43.54046238, -7.744719058, -25.20003459, 
-24.45109345, -106.6043125, NA, -3.880890175), ap = c(223.8746667, 
240.9093333, 222.204, 217.5926667, 214.7616667, 152.1496667, 
249.5276667, 261.6316667, 250.2583333, 169.238, 156.111, 174.5236667, 
266.704, 162.64, 244.4686667, 254.796, 194.3983333, 235.491, 
198.9133333, 159.2223333, 146.703, 148.5333333, 254.0833333)), .Names = c("id", 
"location", "sex", "pc1", "pc1_haw", "condition", "ap"), row.names = 149:171, class = "data.frame")

Comment: I've tried uploading an image of the plot, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

See `?abline` and find that it produces a line through the current plot.
Use instead `lines`

For example:

```
x1 = min(i$condition, na.rm = TRUE)
x2 = max(i$condition, na.rm = TRUE)
plot(i$ap~i$condition, xlab="Condition", ylab="Anal Pad (mm^2)",
   xlim=c(-175,175), ylim=c(0,300), pch=1, frame.plot=F)

lines(x = c(x1, x2), y = c(x1 * reg_i$coefficients[2] + reg_i$coefficients[1], 
      x2 * reg_i$coefficients[2] + reg_i$coefficients[1]))
```

Comment: I cut and pasted your code, and while no error message returned, nothing was added to the plot?

Comment: @M. 0. Since you didn't provide a reproducible example, I tried this code with proxy data and it worked fine. You get the scatterplot but not the line?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - the scatterplot with the data points appear but no line. My data set has 264 individuals, I can try sending you the file someway?

Comment: You can edit your question and give an example of your data using `dput(i)`.

Comment: OK, the column 'condition' has NA values. See my edited answere!